# Makefile compilation

Tags: c, makefile

I have to compile a client.c file; in this file there are macro defined in utiliy_lib.h

When I run  :

```
gcc -Wall -c client.c utility_lib.h
```

The compiler doesn't find macro definitions.

I have this file in the same folder "code":

client.c

server.c

utility_lib.c //it contains generic macro using by every file

utility.c  //it contains utility function, used by client and server

msg_queue.c // it contains function to manipulate message queue (this is a little project for a chatroom)

send_receive.c //it contains function to send and receive message

the makefile that I tried is:

```
CC = gcc -Wall -O0 -g
LDFLAGS = -lpthread
ARCH = $(shell uname -m)

all: client server

server: common.h main.c msg_queue.c send_recv.c util.c
rm -f build/*.o

    $(CC) -c main.c -o build/main.o
    $(CC) -c send_recv.c -o build/send_recv.o
    $(CC) -c util.c -o build/util.o
    $(CC) -c msg_queue.c -o build/msg_queue.o
    $(CC) -o server build/*.o $(LDFLAGS)

client:
    ln -s -f client-$(ARCH) client

:phony
clean:
    rm -f client server build/*.o
```

Anyone could help me please?

Comment: What does this have to do with makefiles? Also, post some code, the issue is probably in your code.

Comment: where is the problem with make?? check your code

Comment: `#include "utility_lib.h"` in c file and use `-IPATH_OF_HEADER`

Comment: in client.c I have obviously #include "utility_lib.h"; I posted only the line for client because it include also other line for server etc

Comment: CC= gcc -Wall
LDFAGS= -lpthread

client: client.c utility_lib.h 
 $(CC) client.c $(LDFLAGS)

Comment: Why are you trying to compile your include file `utility_lib.h` ?

Comment: Is `client.c` in the same folder as `utility_lib.h` ? If it is not the case, add `-I/home/iznogoud/path/to/header_file` to the gcc command. `-I` signals to the compiler that header can be found in this folder. (include search path). Lastly, the header can be correrctly included and macro in the header can remain undefined if this macro are defined according to a condition: `#ifdef CHARLO #define MACROINEED #endif`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Client.C needs to

```
#include "utility_lib.h"
```

Near the top of the file

That gives it the definitions

Then compile is

```
gcc -Wall -c client.c
```